# How to show a google drive html link that is shared with specific people in iframes in google site

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, google-sites

For displaying a google drive html document in an iframe, we first share the file "Public on the web" and take the documnet ID of it. Then this is appended to hosting link(https://googledrive.com/host/) (running this link on browser will display the output of the html file, instead of simply displaying the contents of that file) and given as src to iframe tag. 
   But my requirement is not to share the file publicly, since it has sensitive information. We can set the permission of the google site in such a way that only specific people can access it. For that, the html file should still be shared publicly, which shouldn't happen in my case. 
  Also, in this case, appending document ID of the file whose permission is restricted to hosting link (https://googledrive.com/host/) will give 404 error. Kindly help me on this. Advance thanks.

Comment: If you are going to have to grant access to people so that they can see the google sites page, why don't you just change the permissions on the google document to "Shared with Specific People" so they will have to sign in to get access

Comment: If I restrict the page, then I can't display the page on google site(whatever is the google site share permission). Sounds weird. The page should be public to display on the google site.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to run code that gets the contents of the HTML file, then use an Apps Script Gadget with HTML Service to display the HTML file.

- Add a Google Apps Gadget to your Site.
- Go into the scripts section of your site.
- Create a new Apps Script script
- write code to get the HTML file contents
- return that HTML
- Add the script to the gadget

  The HTML file in your drive will NOT need to be shared with anyone.  The Apps Script however, must run as YOU, in order to access the file.

This code injects the HTML into the Apps Gadget when the Site opens.  I've tested it, and it works.  It gets a HTML file from my Drive, converts the HTML to a String, then serves the HTML into the Site:

```
function doGet() {

  var fileHTML = DriveApp.getFileById('The file ID');
  var theHTML = fileHTML.getBlob().getDataAsString();

  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(theHTML)
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
};
```

To get the file ID of an HTML file in your Drive, right click on the file name, and choose "GET LINK".  Then copy the link.  Inside that link is the file ID.